# Adverbs that don't use 地

Tags: translation, grammar, word-choice

So I know that to make an adverb, you use 'de/di' and put it before the verb like:

> 我兴奋地打开了我的礼物

But in my studies this week I saw this:

> ...病症的人逐年增加

and

> 逐渐成长为独立

Am I right in thinking that these are simply adverbs but to make an adverb from an adjective like 好 or 兴奋 you need a 地？

Comment: not necessarily (only considering adjectives functioning as adverbs), cf.＂外国人实用汉语语法＂  **1.**  下列情况都需要用＂地＂：形容词兼属动词的双音词：他高兴地笑了。表示情态的双音词：他惭愧地低下了头。她轻松地唱了一个歌。双音词的重叠形式：大家舒舒服服地睡了一觉。我们要仔仔细细地汇报。  **２.**  下列情况不用＂地＂：单音词：快走啊！学习语言一定要多听多说。  **３.**  下列情况用不用＂地＂都可以：单音词的重叠形式：学生要好好（地）学习。你们慢慢（地）走。双音词修饰双音动词：我们都努力（地）学习。他全面（地）解释了这个问题。

Answer (score 4):

地 only CHANGES **ADJECTIVES** to adverb. Any adverbs without being conjugated from adjectives can exist without 地.

1. 地 is commonly omitted. This happens usually when the adjective has ONE CHARACTER only. For example: 慢慢走 or 慢走. 地 is omitted since 慢 has only **ONE** character. The repetition of 慢 here is only for the purpose of expressing the action in a more visualized or vivid way.
2. 兴奋 has two characters, and you cannot shorten it to one character to have the same meaning, so we usually don't omit 地 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

(It's been a week, but hope this helps)
There are plenty. Consider:

```
這台機器早晚會出事情。
快給我你的帳單！
我時常搭地鐵去上班。
```

In these phrases, the functions of `早晚`, `快` and `時常` are mostly apt to be seen as adverbs. This being said, the POS in Chinese is not very well-agreed. 
This is due to lack of morphological markers. 
In the ancient time there is no `地` marker, and adjectives also functions as adverbs (like German). 
In these cases, arguably they also look like the complementary adjectives of the subject. 
I guess its advent is probably 20 century, when phrases are so complicated that we often have difficulty parsing, and English-like structures are borrowed into written Chinese.

So back to the question, I would say that when a adverb doesn't cause ambiguity, `地` is often not added. The examples

```
(a)我兴奋地打开了我的礼物。
(b)我兴奋打开了我的礼物。
```

In (b), it cause some confusion (at least when the eye has parsed to `兴奋`) what `兴奋` functions as. But in (b), suffices to say, `地` clears up confusion by reminding you a verb is following.

Last I shall note that even scholars often disagree, as modern Mandarin grammar is not well restricted, and native speakers are generally very tolerant with non-standard phrases. 
I found a [discussion](https://www.zhihu.com/question/23579160). You shall notice that the general consensus does not deem `地` to be not compulsory.

So, append `地` from an adjective if the adjective is several-Charactered (so more difficult to parse), or when the phrase is complicated so that confusion arises.

Comment: That's really clear. Thank you! @aminopterin

Answer (score 1):

An adv doesn't have to be followed by a “地“, such like in "慢慢走“／”好好干“. However, you can always check if a word is an adv by adding a "地" and see if it still make sense. If "yes", then it's an adv. E.g., "慢慢地走"／“好好地干”。